# Showing a subset is an Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

If $F$ is a field (so therefore a ring), and we have $\{ f(x) + g(x) \text{ s.t. } f(x), g(x) \in F[x] \} = I$. I am trying to show that this is an ideal.

I am confused about what we need to show to be an ideal: can I just take any element in the field and multiply it by this set and show that it is in the set?

Comment: What are $f,g,x$? Do you know the definition of ideal?

Comment: I think we're missing some context or you have a small typo in the problem – why do you use the notation $f(x)$ for an element of $F$? Also, fields have no nontrivial ideals, so you might as well just prove $I = F$.

Comment: any field has only two ideals, the trivial $(0)$ and $F$ itself

Comment: I think you mean ideals in the polynomial ring $F[X]$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The f(x) and g(x) are in F[x]

Answer (score 2):

This is confusing because the way you are describing the subset of $F$ that you wish to show is an ideal. It looks like elements of this set are of the form $f(x)$, so I'm assuming you mean that they are polynomials. Thus you mean that $F$ is a field of polynomials. In this case, it is common practice to write $F$ as $F[x]$.

to check that your subset, $I=\{f(x)+g(x) : f(x),g(x) \in F[x]\}$, is an ideal of $F[x]$, you need to check two things:

$1): \forall x,y \in I$, we have that $x+y \in I$.

$2): \forall f(x) \in F[x]$ and $\forall m \in S$, we have that $mf(x) \in I$.

To show $(1)$, lets let $m,n \in I$. Thus $m = f(x) + g(x)$ and $n = r(x) + s(x)$ for $f(x),g(x),r(x),s(x) \in F[x]$.

Since $F[x]$ is a field, we have that $f(x)+g(x) \in F[x]$ and $r(x) + s(x) \in F[x]$. Again, since $F[x]$ is a field, we have that $(f(x)+g(x)) + (r(x)+s(x)) \in F[x]$. This means that $m+n \in I$.

To show $(2)$, let $m \in I$ and $f(x) \in F[x]$. Then again, we have $m = r(x)+s(x)$ for $r(x),s(x) \in F[x]$ by the definition of $m$ being in $I$. Thus $mf(x)=r(x)f(x)+s(x)f(x)$ by the distributive property of $F[x]$. Furthermore, since $F[x]$ is a field, we have that $r(x)f(x),s(x)f(x) \in F[x]$. Thus $mf(x) \in I$ by the defintion of $I$. Thus $I$ is an ideal of $F[x]$.

---

Notice that $I = F[x] + F[x]$. In general, if $R$ is a ring, then $R+R$ is an ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

You could just take $g=0$ and get any $f\in \Bbb F$.  That is, $I=\Bbb F$.  In a field, the only ideals are $0$ and $\Bbb F$.

If you mean the ring $\Bbb F[x]$, the entire ring is of course an ideal.